# Trocar a cor do CheckBox via Styled-Components

Tags: css, react-native, styled-components

Preciso trocar a cor de um `CheckBox` quando está selecionado. Estou usando da seguinte maneira:

`index.js`

```
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
...
<CheckBoxes>
   <Label>Usuário</Label>
   <CheckBox
       disabled={false}
       value={myValue}
       onValueChange={setMyValue}
   />
</CheckBoxes>
```

`styles.js`

```
export const CheckBoxes = styled.View`
  flex: 0.25;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  text-decoration-line: none;

  > input:checked {
      color: #999;
  }
`;
```

Como posso fazer ?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver da seguinte maneira: setando a propriedade `tintColors` do próprio `CheckBox`.

```
<CheckBox
   disabled={false}
   value={isDoctor}
   onValueChange={setIsDoctor}
   tintColors={{ true: '#FC8F00' }}
/>
```